# Show that $\gamma$ is limited to $(a, b)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $ \mathcal{U} = \mathbb {R}^{1 + d}$ and the function $F: \mathbb{R}^{1 + d} \to \mathbb{R}^d $ be continuous and bounded. Show that then for every $ (t_0, x_0) \in \mathbb {R}^{1 + d} $ there is some solution $ \gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb {R}^d$ of the differential equation $x'= F(t, x) $ defined on the whole line $ \mathbb{R} $ with initial condition $ \gamma(t_0) = x_0 $. Is this solution necessarily unique?

this I did:

Let $\gamma: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a maximum solution of $x'=F(t,x)$ and suppose that $b< + \infty$. As $\gamma$ is the solution, it follows from the fundamental Theorem of Calculus that $$ \gamma(t)=x_0+ \int^{t}_{t_0} F(s, \gamma(s)).ds$$
I would like to show that $\gamma$ is limited to (a, b), but I can't.

I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the assumption is that $F$ is bounded, $|F(t,x)|\le M$ for all $(t,x)\in\Bbb R^ {1+d}$, it follows from the integral form of the IVP that
$$
\|γ(t)-x_0\|\le M·|t-t_0|.
$$
Thus there is no divergence at $t=b$, which would be the only way for the solution to leave the domain there.

For uniqueness explore $x'=2\sqrt{\min(1, |x|)}$.